# different style animations with 2 different functions in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm making an animation of an element and i've got some interesting trouble in it. When i'm using .css() method everything works as needed but when i'm using .toggle() it's kind of wrong way it should work. Maybe i've got some lack of knowledge in css but how could a make it with toggling a class to make my code more clear. Two types of animation you could find in a snippet)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.list-header').on('click',function(){
      $(this).children().last().css({'width':'0%','padding-right':'0px'});
    })

    /*
    $('.list-header').on('click',function(){
      $(this).children().last().toggle('hide-span');
    })
   */
    
})
```

```css
  body .list-wrapper {
    margin-top: -16px;
    background: #271726;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: -moz-center;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    padding: 20px 0px 150px 0px; }
    body .list-wrapper .hide-span {
      width: 0% !important;
      padding-right: 0px !important;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      transition: all 1s ease; }
    body .list-wrapper ul a {
      padding: 15px; }
    body .list-wrapper ul li {
      padding: 15px;
      list-style: none;
      width: 70%;
      position: relative; }
      body .list-wrapper ul li span {
        padding-right: 20px; }
      body .list-wrapper ul li .line {
        position: absolute;
        height: 3px;
        top: 50px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 22%;
        z-index: 1;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease;
        transition: all 1s ease; }
    body .list-wrapper ul li:last-child {
      background: #201320;
      display: none;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      transition: all 1s ease; }
    body .list-wrapper ul li:first-child {
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-bottom: 30px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li class="list-header"><span>x</span>toggle<span class="line"></span></li>
        <li>some2</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li class="list-header"><span>x</span>toggle<span class="line"></span></li>
        <li>some2</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li class="list-header"><span>x</span>toggle<span class="line"></span></li>
        <li>some2</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li class="list-header"><span>x</span>toggle<span class="line"></span></li>
        <li>some2</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li class="list-header"><span>x</span>toggle<span class="line"></span></li>
        <li>some2</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li class="list-header"><span>x</span>toggle<span class="line"></span></li>
        <li>some2</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li class="list-header"><span>x</span>toggle<span class="line"></span></li>
        <li>some2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try to use this `$(this).children().last().toggleClass('hide-span');`

Comment: god. so simple) add an answer ill approve) but what is a difference between toggle and toggleClass

Comment: as @ArmKh said you can use toggleClass("hide-span"),
you can also use addClass("hide-span") and removeClass("hide-span") when needed.

Comment: @ddedlink toggle will just hide and show the element, toggleClass will add and remove the class which is provided in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.toggleClass()`

```
$(this).children().last().toggleClass('hide-span');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this class:

```
.hiddenSpan {
   width: 0%; 
   padding-right: 0px; 
}
```

And edit your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.list-header').on('click',function(){
    $(this).children().last().toggleClass('hiddenSpan');
  })

})
```